# remove all but one entity when sorting a group of entities on a tableview cell (Swift5)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sorting

When my code loads 5 entities are displayed on each tableview cell. When I hit a button it sorts the entity but the other 4 entities are still displayed. I have added a photo below to show you exactly what I am looking for. When the objc is pressed it sorts but all of the entities are displayed and i only want 1.

```
   @objc func l1UPBTN(sender: UIButton){
            let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

            let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Data")
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Name", ascending: true)]


            do {
                itemName = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)



                self.theScores.reloadData()
            }catch {
                print("Ashley Tisdale")
            }


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let title = itemName[indexPath.row]
    let cell = theScores.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for : indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 2
    cell.selectionStyle = .default
    let attr1 = title.value(forKey: "atBATS") as? String


    let attr3 = title.value(forKey: "age") as? String
    let attr4 = title.value(forKey: "weight") as? String

    let attr2 = title.value(forKey: "hits") as? String
    let attr5 = title.value(forKey: "positon") as? String

    let text = [attr1,"  Weight :",attr3,"\n","Height : ",attr2," Age : ",attr4," Position :",attr5].flatMap { $0 }.reduce("", +)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(text)"

    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero



    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero


    return cell

}
```

[image]

Comment: try to use `fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1`

Comment: The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArI6B.png) you have attached does not clarify anything. The description of your question is also extremely vague.

Comment: @JaydeepVyas That only prints 1 individual call the rest of the cells no matter what is in them disappear.

Comment: @staticVoidMan basically when I hit a button all 5 core data entities are displayed when there should only be one. Inside the button function it states et fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Data")
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Name", ascending: true)]. So only the entity of Data should be on the tableview cell.